# GStreamer-CRITICAL buffer

Tags: python, buffer, gstreamer, pipeline, loopback

When I execute a gstreamer-1.0 pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -evm videotestsrc ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1
```

for video loop back using `v4l2loopback` version 0.6.3 it thows the following error:

```
"(gst-launch-1.0:17157): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion `buffer != NULL' failed.
```

The behaviour is inconsistent; in 5 attempts, this error comes appears at least 3 times.

System Environment, Ubuntu 12.10, 32bit, 3.5.0-26-generic kernel.

It looks like some problem with the v4l2loopback element, because when I replace the v4l2lopback with fakesink, it didnt throw any error.